# What is wrong with the following bash statement that has a while loop and a if statement

Tags: bash, unix

```
while read line; 
    do if -f live_photos/$line; 
             then cp live_photos/$line other_live_photos 
       fi;  done < other_live_photos.csv
```

What is wrong here? I get an unexpected token near done, error.

other_live_photos.csv is basically a set of file names.

Comment: `do if -f live_photos/$line;` -> `do if [ -f "live_photos/$line" ];` But that should have given you `'-f: command not found'` as error.

Comment: I don't get a syntax error on my system. Are you sure that's your *exact* code? (BTW, the layout seems odd, but as far as I can tell it's legal.)

Comment: You never. Ever. EVER. Use an unquoted shell variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you had an example file so we can determine what the filter criteria are. Based on the idea that there are other entries in `other_live_photos.csv` which do not contain the string `live_photos`:

```
while read line 
do 
 livePhotos=$(grep live_photos $line)
 cp $livePhotos other_live_photos 
done < other_live_photos.csv
```

If it's every line item in the file then just exclude the variable:

```
while read line 
do 
 cp $line other_live_photos 
done < other_live_photos.csv
```

If you are trying to determine if the file in `$line` exists before moving it (what is it going to do if it does not exist? nothing) , then:

```
while read line
 do 
   if [ -f  $line ] 
   then
    cp live_photos/$line other_live_photos 
   fi
 done < other_live_photos.csv
```